# Hi, is there any possibilities for Mobile phone Dual Boot?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

The latest news about ubuntu phone **Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Phone**, my question d is there any possibilities about Dual boot in Android Phone with Ubuntu OS ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can take reference from this:

[DualBootInstallation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation)

Not sure Meizu is on supported list.